# AS3 Error 1046 & 1180

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am trying to make a data grid were name and score is added to it.
I keep getting an error...

1046 Type was not found or was not a complile-time constant: DataProvider.
1080 Call to a possibly undefinded method DataProvider

and here is my coding...

```
var scoreArray = new Array();

D_G.addColumn("player");
D_G.addColumn("score");

enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveScore);

function saveScore(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var obj:Object = new Object();
    obj.player = tb_name.text;
    obj.score = int(tb_score.text);

    scoreArray.Push(obj);

    scoreArray.sortOn("score", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC); 

    var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider (scoreArray);
    D_G.dataProvider = dp;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error happens when you're not including the class you want to use.

Are you using

`import fl.data.DataProvider` ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the DataProvider class ;

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
```

Comment: yeah Thanks I just figured it out... but Thank you

Comment: In looking at your history, you seem to have a habit of not accepting answers. That will make people less likely to answer your questions in the future.